# closing file pointer in Scala in Finally

Tags: scala

In the following code, I am reading no. of lines from a file. If something goes wrong, I'll like to close the file pointer. But how can I find out if `f` contains valid pointer or not?

```
def countLines(filename:String):Option[Int] = {
    try{
        val f = Source.fromFile(filename)
        println(s"no. of lines ${f.getLines().size}")
        Some(f.getLines.size)
    } catch  {
        case ex: FileNotFoundException => {
            println(s"file ${filename} not found")
            None
        }
    } finally {
        //f might not be a valid pointer depending on when the error occured
    }
}
```

The book I am reading uses `var` to maintain state (if `f` is valid or not) but I am trying to avoid it for sake of using only immutable variables.

```
def countLines(filename:String):Option[Int] = {

        var f:Option[Source] = None
        try{
            f = Some(Source.fromFile(filename))
            println(s"no. of lines ${f.get.getLines().size}")
            Some(f.get.getLines.size)
        } catch  {
            case ex: FileNotFoundException => {
                println(s"file ${filename} not found")
                None
            }
        } finally {
            for(i<-f){
                println("closing file")
                i.close()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: is there any reason you have to use a try/catch/finally blocks, rather than a Try object? or would the latter be acceptable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A double `Try()`. This closes the `io` resource even if the `getLines()` fails, but only if the `fromFile()` succeeds.

```
import scala.util.Try

def countLines(filename: String): Option[Int] =
  Try(io.Source.fromFile(filename)).fold(_ => None, {f =>
    val count = Try(f.getLines().length)
    f.close()
    count.toOption
  })
```

Comment: yep, in my solution definitely missed `fold` part

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about this?
If you want Scala-way - i think it's good example for your task:

```
  def countLines(filename: String): Try[Int] = Try(Source.fromFile(filename).getLines.toList.size)

  def test() = {
      val filename = "/etc/passwd"
      countLines(filename) match {
                  case Success(n) => println(n)
                  case Failure(f) => println(f)
                }
       }
```

When n - is a number of our lines, and f - is a Throwable.

Comment: Like it.   The other problem with the original is that in the finally block, f isn't even in scope

Comment: It does not close stream in case `getLines` method fail

Comment: Are you sure? Because i'm not - if we see Source.fromFile - we find:
 () => inputStream.close().
That's why it close stream in case getLines method fail.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
def countLines(filename: String): Option[Int] = {
  val file = Try(Source.fromFile(filename))
  val count = file.map(_.getLines().size)
  (for {
    _ <- count.recoverWith { case _ => file.map(_.close()) }
    lineCount <- count
  } yield lineCount).toOption
}
```

Let's analyze it:

- If file does not exist we will have failed `Try` instance and method returns `None`. In this case you do not need to clear any resources as no actual stream was created.
- If `getLines` fails for any reason or anything else during processing goes south we will close created stream in first line of for comprehension

Hope it helps

Comment: @jwvh you can still call map on it

Answer (score 0):

Simply, how about this:

```
def numLines(fileName:String):Option[Int] = {
  try {
    val f = scala.io.Source.fromFile(fileName)
    try { Some(f.getLines.size) }
    catch { case ex: IOException =>
      Console.err.println("i/o excetion")
      None
    }
    finally { f.close() }
  }
  catch {
    case ex: FileNotFoundException =>
      Console.err.println("file not found")
      None
  }
}
```